# Is there an Instaloader function to download a limited number of posts from a GraphSidecar?

Tags: python, download, iterator, instagram-api, instaloader

After spending the better half of 2 hours trying to get my code to download a certain number of posts from a Sidecar post using the Instaloader module, I can't seem to find a good solution.

I have come up with a needlessly complex way to do this, which I haven't implemented yet, and I'm hoping I can save that as a last resort.

A snippet of my code so far

```
    def _download_post(self, post, source, sidecar_limit):
        # Get the @sidecar_limit of posts in a sidecar
        if post.typename == 'GraphSidecar':
            nodes  = post.get_sidecar_nodes(end=sidecar_limit)
            return self.loader.posts_download_loop(nodes, target='downloads')

        # Otherwise download post normally
        self.loader.download_post(post, source)
```

My problem comes from the iterable `nodes` which contains namedtuples that don't contain many needed attributes that normal post Classes would have. Such as `date_utc`

Finally it would be nice to specify that I want to only download videos or images only from the Sidecar. I do have function which does this for me already, and the `posts_download_loop` function does accept a callable which when returning `False` will cancel the download and return. However I don't want the function to return, I'd like it to `continue` and skip to the next posts. But I'm not sure if there is a way to do this. It's alright if there isn't as this isn't my main problem.

Any help with finding the correct Instaloader function would be very helpful. Thanks.